# How can we get data from mysql database in angular 7 application by using node.js and display it on angular component html page

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, typescript

I have tried every thing but i cant under stand how to reach my goal.
Now my main goal is that i want to get data from mysql database and then access this information  in angular component which is page-one.component.ts file. Now i can connect to the database and can get the data from database in server.js file. but i cant understand how to get the information in angular component. The method i have tried so far is that i include the server.js file in angular.json file and then include the function "get_data" (get_data function fetch data from database in server.js file) in my page-one.component.ts file and then i call the function in page-one.component.ts file. The function is called, but the problem is that i got error in server.js file that  " Cannot read property 'createConnection' of undefined". This error stops me from getting the information from database. but when i call this get_data function in server.js file i got the database information and i can print the information in console. 
Can any one give me the solution please.
I think the error is because of the context of variable.
but please guide me.

My server.js file code.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));

});

var mysql = require('mysql');

var dbconfig = {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mydb"
}

var con = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig);
con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});


 get_data();   

 function get_data(){

    console.log("function called");

    var con = this.mysql.createConnection(dbconfig);  ===> GOT ERROR HERE

    con.query("SELECT * FROM teacher", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });

}

server.listen(port, () => {

    console.log(`server running on port ${port} `);
})
```

My page-one.component.ts file code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

declare function get_data(): any; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-one',
  templateUrl: './page-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-one.component.css']
})
export class PageOneComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    get_data();
  }

}
```

My angular.json file code.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myapp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myapp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": 
            [
              "server.js" ===> INCULDED THE SERVER.JS FILe HERE
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myapp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "myapp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "myapp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "myapp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "myapp"
}
```

" Cannot read property 'createConnection' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

```html
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: '',
  connectionLimit: 10,
  queueLimit: 0
});
connection.promise((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('connected!');
});
module.exports = connection.promise();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```html
app.get("/youroute", (req, res, next) => {
    "use strict";
    const getProduct = "SELECT * FROM yourtable";
    database.query(getProduct, (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' })
      };
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "",
        product: rows,
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you read [how to write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This should help you to avoid being down voted.

Answer (score -1):

```html
Service for Angular

export interface You {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    content: string
  }
Get Method on Model Angular

getData() {
      this.http.get<{message:string,name:Name[]}>("URL")
    .subscribe(result =>{
      console.log(result);
    });
and in HTML make For Loop with NGFOR for display your data
```